# Spark: keys intersection in RDDs with different key types

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, set, dataset, rdd

Consider the following situation, you have two RDDs of key-value pairs, where each of the two keys from the two RDDs are of different type. 
RDD1(Vector[String], String) look like this:

```
(Vector("A", "B", "E"), "bla bla bla"),
(Vector("W"), "bla bla bla bla"),
(Vector("C", "M"), "bla bla bla bla bla"),
(Vector("A", "V"), "bla bla bla")
...
```

RDD2[(String, String)] look like this:

```
("A", 12),
("B", 434),
("C", 8023),
("D", 3454),
...
("N", 251)
```

Note: that keys in RDD2 are from A-N inclusive.
The desired output is pairs of the first RDD1 such that every string in the Vector key is a subset of the entire set of keys of RDD2

```
(Vector("A", "E", "B"), "bla bla bla"),
(Vector("C", "M"), "bla bla bla bla bla")
```

also if this is not possible with RDDs, I'd like to know how other abstractions like dataframe and dataset could achieve this result

Answer (score 0):

```
def myFilter(rdd1: RDD[(Vector[String],String)], rdd2: RDD[(String,String)]): RDD[(Vector[String],String)] = {

    val keys = rdd2.map(_._1).collect()

    val filtered = rdd1.filter{ entry =>
      entry._1.forall(str => keys.contains(str))
    }
    filtered
}
```

This is not the most efficient way of getting it done, but gets the job done.

Comment: thanks for your answer. FYI you could've used val keys = rdd2.keys.collect() which is more readable. However I'm still looking for a way of getting this results with RDD transformatinos or using other abstractions, which I'm less familiar with like dataframe and dataset.